# Cannot open IOS simulator after version update

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator

I updated my MAC Book Air to OS X El Capitan. After that I cannot open my Xcode, So I deleted older version of Xcode and installed new (Xcode 7.3.1). Now the IOS simulator doesn't open up also getting an message box.

> You can't open the application "iOS Simulator" because it is in the Trash.
>   To open this application, move it from the Trash.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by updating my IOS Simulator through Xcode preferences and finally it works properly.

```
Steps to solve the issues.

1. Open Xcode
2. XCode -> Preferences -> Components 
3. Update latest version of IOS Simulator.
```

[image]

Comment: This does not actually have anything to do with the reported problem.  These downloads just install simulator runtime content to /Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles.  Likely the thing that actually helped here was time or emptying your trash.

Answer (score 0):

Try to fully uninstall Xcode including all the file and folders then download a new copy of Xcode for better installation. Maybe that'll work.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like LaunchServices is in a state where it knows about your old Simulator.app in the trash but no the one in the installed Xcode.app.  Run this from Terminal:

```
open $(xcode-select -p)/Applications/Simulator.app
```